# Suppress Pipeline Output in Jenkins file

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

When I run a build on my jenkins it always prints the pipeline while moving through the jenkins steps. The current output of the console:

```
Build context: CI
:clean
:app:clean
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 22s
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] properties
[Pipeline] sh
```

I want to see only the actual executions I've declared. The console ouput should look like

```
Build context: CI
:clean
:app:clean
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 22s
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed
```

Comment: See [JENKINS-41845](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-41845) for how you can do this.

Comment: Where should I put the ".pipeline-annotated" in my pipeline?

Comment: I think the idea is to add a plugin "Simple Theme" and add it there. 
What this does is just hide it from view in your browser using CSS. I don't like this aproach and there seems to be no real solution for declogging the log after 4 years.

Comment: It does not make any sense to just hide it. Also it doesn't make any sense to output the script contained in the pipeline. So why should I mask this wrong behaviour?