# How to reduce the console output of a Jenkins Groovy pipeline job?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins job implemented as a groovy pipeline with some windows batch calls (NOT bash shell) in it. The Jenkins console output is very verbose, so every line of the groovy script, even the curly braces "{" are being displayed...

Example:

```
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
```

I actually expected this to be a simple Jenkins setting... However after reading a dozen of links I could not find any useful solution for this particular case - a groovy pipeline (with some windows batch calls in it).

Anyone know a way to solve this?

Comment: See answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51110083/suppress-scripted-pipelines-output-in-jenkins

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly enough there's an open bug for this: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-45210

Answer (score 0):

You can quiet those down by altering the Extra CSS field in Jenkins' System Configuration. I added the following:

```css
.pipeline-new-node {
    display: none;
}
```

[image: Jenkins Extra CSS]